# Hillshade effect not working when no data is on screen

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, hillshade

I'm working on a DEM and I selected hillshade effect to be active.
The problem is that I can't get it to appear when a no-data area is shown on my screen.
If I move the area just enough for the no-data area to disappear from my screen then hillshade works just fine again.
I couldn't find a setting to correct that. I also tried to color the no data area but that didn't change the result.[image: Hillshade working fine]

[image: No data appears and hillshade stops working]

[image: No data appears and hillshade stops working]

Comment: I am not sure if I got you right, did you try to change NoData value to No Color from Symblogy? Symbology -> Check "Display Background Value (RGB)".